# Entering the Vault

Tags: pattern, story, cipher

*I got closer to the vault. I knew someone clever created this. But who? I arrived to the door. It was password protected. Although lot of my memory was deleted, the place seemed to me so familiar. I also had the paper – I found at the place, where my mind was erased. I read it again:*

> When mathematics and rabbits meet, something happens –
>
> > π γ γ ω α τ β γα ωγ αδ ττ βμ γδδ ωαα ακκ
>
> However, the truth is masked... –
>
> > 2333233333223332333322332333333332
>
> 10 people will understand this, which one are you? –
>
> > βμγγγγγκγγδαωγπωγπτγγδγγτγγεαωμμγγγγπμγγωμκγγπγπτγγγγγπαωαδγγγγπωαωγπγγπβγπγγγβγπγγγπγγεγπδαδ
>
> If you don't, then you are not one of twelve,
>
> If you do, then you will arise as doctor!
>
> *-Someone, you hate*

*Then I got, what it means, and I opened the vault...*

Who is the narrator and what is the password to the vault?

Comment: Since I'm new to Puzzling SE and I'm not native English speaker, any advice in creating puzzles (e.g. tags) or any correction in the question (text) is welcome.

Comment: This looks like a good puzzle. May I suggest an edit to the first bit: π γ γ ω α τ β γα ωγ (instead of ωα ) ... Apologies if I'm wrong but I have a hunch.

Comment: @hexomino Yes, you are right, thank you very much. It's a typo and my apologies.

Comment: Is the weird punctuation in the opening narration part of the riddle?  (ie, the comma after "knew", the hyphen after "the paper", etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First clue:

> clearly references the Fibonacci sequence, with each Greek letter denoting a digit: π=0 γ=1 ω=2 α=3 δ=4 τ=5 ε=6 κ=7 β=8 μ=9

Second clue:

> Between this and the bit about 10 people understanding, some sort of bit masking is going to happen. using the key above, the text comes out to:   891111171143210210511411511632991111091129711010511111032341111023210110810111810111011610434

Launching off from Matt's continuation....

> We use the mask to group the digits to form ASCII codes, which translate to: Your first companion "of eleventh". The 11th Doctor's first companion was Amy Pond.

The Narrator:

> The Doctor himself.

The note writer:

> The same Doctor, pre- memory wipe. The Doctor may actually hate many things (pears for example), but the only single individual he loathes, is himself (reference the 11th Doctor episode "Amy's Choice" for a quite literal example)

The password:

> Amy Pond

Comment: Second clue is not spoilered.

Comment: I always mess SOME part up, and have to take a couple of stabs at getting it right :\

Comment: Anyway, you got the first clue right. Use the resources, I'm not saying more.

Comment: I added this, as answer, because you stated the narrator in the conclusion, but everybody did a good work.

Answer (score 6):

I made some progress working from Irishpanda's answer.

Who is the narrator / What is the password?

I don't know *yet*, but at this point, I will guess that the answer to one of those is

> Amy Pond

The sequence from the second clue

> `891111171143210210511411511632991111091129711010511111032341111023210110810111810111011610434`

This can be separated into groups of 2 and 3 digits using the mask (thanks, LeppyR64)

> `89 111 117 114 32 102 105 114 115 116 32 99 111 109 112 97 110 105 111 110 32 34 111 102 32 101 108 101 118 101 110 116 104 34`
>
>  Mapping this as ASCII codes to letters:
>
>  **Your first companion "of eleventh"**

If you don't, then you are not one of twelve,

If you do, then you will arise as doctor!

> This is a reference to Dr. Who. There have been 12 iterations of the Doctor. I'm no expert, but after some digging, I found the eleventh Doctor, Matt Smith, and his first companion, **Amy Pond.**

Comment: I thought the mask was how you broke up the groups of digits.

Comment: I think you're right, it matches up.

Comment: Wow. Thanks, @LeppyR64! I'll update my answer.

Comment: don't feel right putting it in my answer, since you made the final leap. I'm pretty sure this is a message from the Doctor to *himself*. The theme of the Doctor's self-loathing has shown up in all the new series Doctors. See the episode "Amy's Choice" for an very literal example for the 11th Doctor.

Comment: Go ahead, if you know it, take it! I have no familiarity with the show, so I would feel bad taking credit for some Google Fu

Comment: I agree with @IrishPanda but I'm confused by the "10 people will understand this".

Comment: Its an old joke: "There are 10 kinds of people in the world, those that understand binary, and those that don't" . 10 is binary for the number 2.

Comment: The thing that makes me feel dumb, is I saw that sequence of 114,115,116 and thought, "Huh, that's odd" and didn't follow up on it.

Comment: @Irishpanda The two answers are right, which one should I accept? I wasn't avtive for a while, since I'm living in Europe.

Comment: As the question asker, that choice is yours.